# How to use inheritance for passing a query?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, inheritance

Here is the structure of my codes. I want to know, how can I optimize it? In other word, How can I write the `INSERT` query just one time? *(because it is constant for all methods)*.

```
class Main { // here is some code }

class Test extends Main{

    private $post_id;

    public function __construct($post_id, PDO $db)
    {
        $this->post_id = $post_id;
    }

    public function func1()
    {
        // connect to database    
        INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed (post_id, username) 
                           VALUES ($this->post_id, $_SESSION['username']);

    }

    public function func2()
    {
        // connect to database    
        INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed (post_id, username) 
                           VALUES ($this->post_id, $_SESSION['username']);

    }

    public function func3()
    {
        // connect to database    
        INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed (post_id, username) 
                           VALUES ($this->post_id, $_SESSION['username']);

    }

}
```

Can I write that `INSERT` query in the `Main` class? Or how can I prevent of duplicate codes? *(I mean is that `INSERT` code)*

Comment: @u_mulder What do you mean exactly?! I always need to one of those function. Or `func1`, or `func2`, or `func3`.

Comment: If they do the same - why do you keep them all?

Comment: @u_mulder No they are not the same, They just need to same `INSERT` query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you have in mind but given the code you've posted:

```
class Main {
    // ...
    protected funtion foo() {
        // connect to database    
        INSERT IGNORE INTO viewed (post_id, username) 
        VALUES ($this->post_id, $_SESSION['username']);
    }
}

class Test extends Main {

    public function func1()
    {
        // ...
        $this->foo();
    }

    public function func2()
    {
        // ...
        $this->foo();
    }

    public function func3()
    {
        // ...
        $this->foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Seems good. I edited your code a bit. What is your opinion about it? (because there is several class like `Test` and all of them need to `foo()`)

Comment: If that is what you want/need, ok. Your description just didn't force the need of having the method in the base class - could be a good idea, could be not ;-)

Comment: According to my needs, I think writing `foo()` in the `Main` class is the best solution for me. Also +1 for you.

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but I have a small question. please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92cf615a682dc43426a8). Thanks.